# How to make counter two digit even if below 10 on timer

Tags: javascript, timer, setinterval

I have as simple timer as below, but how do I make it show two digits when it falls below 10, for 09, 08, 07, 06 etc.?

```
startTimer(60);
function startTimer(num){
      count = num;
      countdown = setInterval(function(){
             count--;
      }, 1000);
     };
```

Answer (score 4):

The required string formatting is easy:

```
var str = (count < 10) ? '0' + count : count;
```

However, you need to ensure there's some way to *stop* the counter too.  It's often preferable to use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`, and only set up a new timer if you know that the current value is greater than zero.

Answer (score 0):

`var str = (count < 10) ? '0' + count : count;`

this worked for me, for setInterval() for my Pomodoro project.